# Why does this give "undefined" error?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the user to put something into the text area and  the output should be what he wrote repeapiting x amount of times, but I get an error "document.forme is undefined".

Can you please help me understand why it is undefined?

My code:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>input home work</title>
<script type="text/javascript">


 var help= document.forme.tryout.value;

 for (x=1; x<=10;x++){

 function numberCheak (){

     document.write("this is"+"  "+help++);

     }


 }
  </script>


  </head>

 <body>
<form name="forme">

<input name="tryout" type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="click me" onClick="numberCheak();"/>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, the "homework" tag is encouraged.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you have a few problems. The first is that you are trying to access a form element that doesn't exist yet: the script is above the form element, so the form doesn't exist when you try to get it. If you move the script to the bottom of the page it will work better.

Second, the loop should be inside the function, not wrapped around the function.

Third, `document.write` has weird side effects and causes the document to be rewritten and will stop the script from continuing correctly.

Here's my revised script

```
function numberCheak() {
    var help = document.forme.tryout.value;
    for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += help;
    }
}
```

and the HTML form that goes with it

```
<form name="forme" id="forme">
    <input name="tryout" type="text" /> 
    <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="numberCheak();" /> 
    <span id="output"></span>
</form>
```

You can [see it in action on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zpax9/1/)

Answer (score -2):

Forms are stored in collection and can be accessed like this:

`var form = document.forms[i];`
or
`var form = document.forms[name];`

In your case, `i` is 0 and `name` is forme.

Comment: The method he used, `document.forme.tryout.value` actually is valid Javascript to get the form value. You can try it. The reason it is undefined in his case is because the script is running before the form is loaded in the page.